# Paginating hierarchical data using closure tables (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data, transitive-closure-table

I am trying to query paged hierarchical comments sorted by `score`. `score` is an integer, and the comments table has a self-referential `parent_id` column.

Each page should have **at least one root comment followed by its children**. If only one root comment is in the dataset, than only one page will be returned.

So, given the following data in the `comments` table:

```
+----+-------+-----------+
| id | score | parent_id |
+----+-------+-----------+
|  1 |    10 |      NULL |
|  2 |     5 |      NULL |
|  3 |     0 |         1 |
|  4 |     6 |         2 |
|  5 |     0 |      NULL |
|  6 |    30 |         1 |
|  7 |     1 |         3 |
|  8 |     0 |         4 |
|  9 |    50 |      NULL |
| 10 |     2 |         2 |
+----+-------+-----------+
```

I'd like to be able to `SELECT * FROM comments`...`LIMIT 4 OFFSET 0` and have **Page 1** be:

```
+----+-------+-----------+
| id | score | parent_id |
+----+-------+-----------+
|  9 |    50 |      NULL |
|  1 |    10 |      NULL |
|  6 |    30 |         1 |
|  3 |     0 |         1 |
+----+-------+-----------+
```

And **Page 2** be:

```
+----+-------+-----------+
| id | score | parent_id |
+----+-------+-----------+
|  2 |     5 |      NULL |
|  4 |     6 |         2 |
| 10 |     2 |         2 |
|  5 |     0 |      NULL |
+----+-------+-----------+
```

And **Page 3** be blank because no root comments remain.

I'm using a supporting closure table, as described by [Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin), because comment subtrees can be viewed independently using any comment as the root comment, and this seems like the best solution for that.

The **structure and sample data** for the table in question is the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `comments` (`id`, `score`, `parent_id`)
VALUES
  (1,10,NULL),
  (2,5,NULL),
  (3,0,1),
  (4,6,2),
  (5,0,NULL),
  (6,30,1),
  (7,1,3),
  (8,0,4),
  (9,50,NULL),
  (10,2,2);

CREATE TABLE `comments_closure` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ancestor` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `descendant` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `depth` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `comments_closure` (`id`, `ancestor`, `descendant`, `depth`)
VALUES
  (1,1,0), (1,3,1), (1,6,1), (1,7,2),
  (2,2,0), (2,4,1), (2,10,1), (2,8,2),
  (3,3,0), (3,7,1),
  (4,4,0), (4,8,1),
  (5,5,0),
  (6,6,0),
  (7,7,0),
  (8,8,0),
  (9,9,0),
  (10,10,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for a 1-level deep query:

```
SELECT @id_multiplier := MAX(POW(10, -(length(id) + 1))) FROM comments;
SELECT @score_multiplier := @id_multiplier * MAX(POW(10, -(length(score) + 1))) FROM comments;
SELECT c1.id
     , c1.score
     , c1.parent_id 
FROM comments c1
LEFT JOIN comments c2 
   ON c1.parent_id = c2.id
WHERE c1.parent_id IS NULL 
   OR c1.parent_id IN 
     (SELECT id FROM comments WHERE parent_id IS NULL)
ORDER BY 
   IF(ISNULL(c1.parent_id)
    , c1.score
    , c2.score + (c1.parent_id * @id_multiplier) - (1-(c1.score * @score_multiplier))
    ) DESC
```